# Number of vertices and edges lies on the boundary of bounded cells in line arrangement

Tags: computational-geometry

I am learning computational geometry by myself using [these lecture notes](https://geometry.inf.ethz.ch/gca18-8.pdf) from ETH Zurich. Here is an exercise (8.9) I have been stuck for a few days:

> For a line arrangement $A$ of a set of $n$ lines in $R^2$, let $F$ denote the union of the closure of all bounded cells. Show that the complexity
> (number of vertices and edges of the arrangement lying on the boundary) of $F$ is
> $O(n)$.

My intuition is to use induction, proving that when a new line $l$ is added, the number of added edges is a constant. This is similar to how we proved the zone theorem. However, I cannot figure it out. Can someone provide me with some hints?

Comment: Observation: Although each cell is convex, the union of all cells is not necessarily. Example: https://imgur.com/ooiYWS6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider 3 additional lines such that their arrangement consists of a single bounded (triangular) cell $C$ and $F \subset C$. Then every edge of $F$ belongs to a zone (using a terminology from your textbook) of at least one of the 3 added lines. And all 3 zones of 3 added lines contain at most $30n$ edges according to Zone Theorem. So $F$ has no more than $30n$ edges which is $O(n)$.

Comment: Or use a bounding triangle for $\le 30n$ edges.

Comment: @j_random_hacker
Thank you, I've edited the answer.